# How can I handle browser tab close event in React? Only close, not refresh

Tags: reactjs

My goal is when browser tab closed calling function logout.

Is it possible? Can I handle browser tab close event without refresh case?

If I use beforeunload or unload events, function triggered when user refresh page, I don't want this, I want just run when closed tab.

How can I do this in React Js?

Comment: Try to use event.preventDefault() in your logout functuion to disable refresh

Comment: still didnt work @val

Comment: @ValeriiVoronkov

Comment: Have you consider using a package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beforeunload